# "Permission denied" when uploading an image through Imgur's API in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image in Android.  The documentation for the header can be found here: https://api.imgur.com/#authentication.

I am using the following line of code to authorize my app:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization:", "Client-ID " + Constants.MY_IMGUR_CLIENT_ID);
```

I keep getting the response:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Permission Denied
```

Is the header wrong or do I need to look elsewhere in my code to find the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

> httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " +
>   Constants.MY_IMGUR_CLIENT_ID);

(without colon)?

Comment: I just tried it. Now the error is "Bad Request" instead of "Permission Denied".  Would that indicate that the authorization is now correct and I am doing something wrong elsewhere now?

Comment: [This is what imgur api says about that](http://api.imgur.com/errorhandling#400), so it seem your error is somewhere else now.

Comment: Well I am one step closer...  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The following has worked for me before:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + Constants.MY_IMGUR_CLIENT_ID);
```

Notice the missing colon